# How to Write Nested Query Connecting three table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am creating a site like social network. I Have 3 table. I am finding each users and their number of total friends and number of friends who are blocked.

```
    1. tbl_Registrations

    |   Id  |   FirstName   |
    *************************
        1       User1   
        2       User2
        3       User3   
        4       User4
        5       User5
        6       User6
        7       User7
        8       User8


    2.tbl_Friends

    |   Id  |   SenderId    |   ReciverId   |  Status   |

        1           1               2          Accept
        2           3               1          Accept
        3           4               1          Accept
        4           2               3          Accept
        5           3               8          Accept
        6           4               2          Accept  
        7           4               3          Accept
        8           8               4          Accept

  3. tbl_Status

   |    Id  |   UserId  |   Status  |

        1         1         Blocked
        2         3         Blocked
        3         4         Allowed
        4         2         Blocked
        5         6         Blocked
        6         5         Allowed
        7         8         Blocked
        8         7         Allowed
```

my query is

```
SELECT tbl_Registrations.FirstName, COUNT(*) AS TotalFriends
FROM tbl_Friends INNER JOIN tbl_Registrations ON tbl_Friends.SenderId = tbl_Registrations.Id 
OR tbl_Friends.ReciverId = tbl_Registrations.Id
WHERE (tbl_Friends.Status = 'Accept')
GROUP BY tbl_Registrations.FirstName
```

Using my query i will get only name and total friends. How to include find count of blocked Friends in the same query.

my expected output is

```
|    FirstName   |  TotalFriendsCount   |    BlockedFriendsCount   |
```

Comment: your tbl_Status doesn't make sense for me, how do you know UserID 1 is Blocked? He is blocked by whom?

Comment: Blocked by Admin. I doing Admin Part. In admin side i am listing user list and their friends count and blocked friends count @Veljko89

Comment: So you wanna say tbl_Friends.Status can be 'Blocked'? I just can't figure out which column is showing BlockedFriends

Comment: tbl_Friends.Status represent whether friend request is accepted or rejected and tbl_Status.Status represent the user is blocked or not @Veljko89

Comment: Don't tag products not involved... Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server here?

Comment: I am using mssql. but that doesnt matter. if someone is answering  in MySQL @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT tbl_Registrations.FirstName, 
        COUNT(*) AS TotalFriends,
        (   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_Status
            WHERE [Status]  = 'Blocked'
                AND (UserId = tbl_Friends.SenderId
                    OR UserId = tbl_Friends.ReciverId)
                AND UserId <> tbl_Registrations.id ) BlockedFriendsCount
FROM tbl_Friends 
INNER JOIN tbl_Registrations ON tbl_Friends.SenderId = tbl_Registrations.Id 
    OR tbl_Friends.ReciverId = tbl_Registrations.Id
WHERE (tbl_Friends.Status = 'Accept')
GROUP BY tbl_Registrations.FirstName
```

Comment: I am getting error: Column tbl_Friends.SenderId is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause.Column tbl_Friends.ReciverId is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause. Column tbl_Registrations.Id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause.@Abdul Rasheed